# How can I select items from a table but ban certain from another?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have two tables, one contains entities other entitylog.

MyEntity:

```
id, lat, lon
```

A entity has a position in the world.

MyEntityLog:

```
id, otherid, otherlat, otherlon
```

Entity with id has interacted with otherid at otherid's latitude and longitude.

For instance, I have the following entities:

```
1, 4.456, 2.234
2, 3.344, 6.453
3, 6.234, 9.324
```

(not very accurate, but it serves the purpose).

Now, If entity 1 interact with 2 the result on the log table would look like:

```
1, 2, 3.344, 6.453
```

So my question is, how can I for listing entity 1's available interactions NOT include the ones on the log table?

The result of listing entity 1's available interactions should be only be entity 3 as it already has a interaction with 2.

Comment: I would use EF5 DbGeography and but otherwise I'm not sure what you are doing. Could yuou elaborate on what ypu are after?
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a list of `id`s that interact with `entity 1`:

```
var id1 = 1;
var excluded = from l in db.EntityLogs
               where l.id == id1
               select l.otherid;
```

then find the entries not having an `id` in this list or equal to `id1`:

```
var logs= from l in db.EntityLogs
               where !excluded.Contains(l.id) && l.id != id1
               select l;
```

Note that linq will defer the execution of `excluded` and incorporate it in the execution of `logs`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, I guess I need more details, but if you want to list the entities that have no entry in log table, one solution will be something like this, assuming myEntities is the collection of MyEntity and myEntityLogs is the collection of MyEntityLog

```
var firstList = myEntities.Join(myEntityLogs, a => a.Id, b => b.Id, (a, b) => a).Distinct();
var secondList = myEntities.Join(myEntityLogs, a => a.Id, b => b.OtherId, (a, b) => a).Distinct();

var result = myEntities.Except(firstList.Concat(secondList)).ToList();
```